# can we use webRTC for offline communication?

Tags: expo, webrtc, react-native-webrtc

Can we use webRTC in react-native expo for offline communication between devices on the same local network?

I tried to find info about it but didn't got any idea. I'd also refered to this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCIceServer but didn't got anything.
Please help if you have any idea on this one. Thanks